# CakePHP baking fixtures doesn't care about unique fields

Tags: cakephp

An example:
I have a User model with a field 'username'
In the `$validate` array, I have set 'isunique' rule for 'username'. It works, no problem.

But every time I generate fixture, the auto generated value for this field is not unique.

Same problem for other models.

Any idea how to get bake to produce unique values for fileds with 'isunique' rule?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even think cake/fixtures would so such a thing?
It doesnt!

Your validation rules have absolutely nothing to do with your indexes.
Validation get triggered when using validates() or save().
But your database does not have to have those "unique" indexes for it to work.

If you really want them in your fixtures, too, you need to define them there manually (see the primary key index on how to do that).

Comment: _"If you really want them in your fixtures, too, you need to define them there manually (see the primary key index on how to do that)."_

Did you mean set it in the database? I have set the key to 'UNI' in the DB (both the test and default). But the generated fixture still contains duplicates. The $fields array is correct. I have pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/TUfPBYnH

In the above I need the 'name' to be unique.

If cannot use fixture, is there any way to generate dummy data that is valid according to the validation rules?

Comment: No, i mean what i write: In your fixture (the Fixture.php file so to speak). If you want valid dummy data, you also need to do that in your fixture. Just dont write the same value twice there.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to do it other than writing it manually? I mean any way to generate this automatically?